# How to get a callback response from a rails select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a code like:

`<%= select_tag 'script-switcher', options_for_select(@scripts), prompt: "Choose" ,
         data: {
         remote: true,
         url: url_for(mypath_path(current_store)) }
    %>`

How can I get the html response?

Comment: Just write a javascript to do this, this is not a common behaviour for rails application.

Comment: How? The user will select an item, then I'll return some partial to show, but using ajax, because I don't want to reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved doing this:

.js.coffee

`$('#script-switcher').bind "ajax:success", (event,data) ->
    $('.value-copy').html(data)`

.html.erb

`<%= select_tag 'script-switcher', options_for_select(@scripts),
         data: {
         remote: true,
         url: url_for(my_path()) }
    %>`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get html response with remote: true.

remote: true sends a js request(ajax request) and you will get a js response. remove it to get html response.

Comment: But I need to do this to render a partial through ajax.

A user will select an item, then I'll return a partial depending on selected item

Comment: yes just render the partial in the js.erb or js.haml file which has the same name as the controller action. example: create.js.erb

Comment: $('#some_element').html("#{escape_javascript(render 'partial_name')}") in the js.erb file.

Comment: Yeah, but the partial will be returned by my server application. My problem is how to get this return